# Expose Visual Basic string functions

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I'm trying to use some Visual Basic string manipulation functions in a Blue Prism code stage. Referencing functions like `LEN`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT` throws an error:

> 'Len' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Is there a DLL or namespace I can import to my Business Object in order to expose and use these functions?

Comment: This question shouldn't be put on hold. While I completely agree the question itself needs some work, the core of the issue is still that the OP is asking about how to expose Visual Basic string manipulation functions in a Blue Prism code stage (which are not enabled by default).

Comment: Why is this on hold? This is a legitimate, on-topic question as it relates to Blue Prism and RPA, the answer to which would address/answer many future questions in regards to utilizing system libraries and the .NET frameworks.

Comment: @AlexP In Stackoverflow, the community has moderation tools. The question likely went to the new questions queue and the people who found the question to be off-topic might not be familiar with BP/rpa (did a quick check on them and none have any posts in any of those two tags). Also, one person might vote it as off-topic, then the others simply followed suit seeing the already present vote.

Comment: @Jerry There also may be some confusion after my edits to the question - it was originally tagged with `VBA` and `DLL`.

Answer (score 2):

`LEN`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT` are available through the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` library.

In the Code Options tab of the properties of the Initialize page of your object, add `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` as an entry in the "External References" section, and add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as an entry in the "Namespace Imports" section.

After that, you can begin to use the string manipulation functions available in the [Visual Basic spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions).

Answer (score -1):

The function you mentioned len, left and right is already provided by BluePrism.

You have to open the `calculation stage` there would by default function provided by Blue prism in left bottom box called Functions. [image] Select `Text` option under that you can find the function related to string.

In visual basic, to calculate the length of string `Length()` function is used not `Len`